# How to add Python to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. I couldn't find how to add Python there. So I had to install Visual Studio Preview 2017 with Python (as they advise [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installation)). So now I have 2 installations of VS 2017 which is not good. Is there any way to install python support to VS 2017(not preview)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 5/6/2017 the only way to use the python tools in visual studio 2017 is through the preview channel.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the **Python development** workload by selecting the **Workloads** tab and scrolling down to **Web & Cloud**. Once selected, you can check additional optional components under the **Summary** to the right.

[image: Pythod Development Workload]

Answer (score 1):

Since yesterday, you can install the Python Workload using your Visual Studio 2017installer.